# Is there a type of nothing type in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is there any data types of nothing available in javascript? I mean like not the null or undefined or 'empty string' but pure nothing. For example, i want to print a variable to console; `console.log(variable)` it should prints nothing. Is there something like that? Because i needed in do operations in array. Like `` [x === true ? "Script": `!this should be nothing not empty string but nothing!`] `` if i print that array i want to see just empty array not null or undefined in that array.

Comment: 3 nothing types are `null`, `undefined` and `false`

Comment: this is somewhat available via typescript, [see more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50977783/how-to-set-a-type-parameter-to-nothing-in-typescript)

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen `false` is not a type. And if you extend "nothing" to mean "falsy values", then why not also list `""`, `0`, `NaN` and `0n`?

Comment: Javascript already has one notion too many for "nothing"... Let's not make things worse ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your actual problem, you can use the spread operator (assuming you have multiple values):

To answer your question, however -- no, that does not exist. The closest you can get to that is `undefined` which exists when trying to access "undefined" JSON properties (try doing `window.x` in inspect element)

```js
function printOutArrayOptionally(flag) {
  return [...(flag ? ["Value"] : [])]
}

console.log(printOutArrayOptionally(true))
console.log(printOutArrayOptionally(false))
```

Answer (score 3):

No, there is not. The `undefined` value comes closes to what you want, but [an array with a value is still distinguishable from an array without a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683773/what-is-undefined-x-1-in-javascript).

You'll need to write

```
x === true ? ["Script"] : []
```

instead.